# How to create a Google Plus Brand Page not associated with a Google Plus account

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-pages

I have a Google Plus account and could successfully create a brand page that is associated with that account.

But I created that account with the sole purpose of having the brand page.

So I will not post anything or interact with people on the account, just on the brand page.

But the account is the default. So already I've mistakenly posted things on the account thinking I was on the brand page.

So, I don't want to have the account, just the brand page.

Another reason for that is that I got the right to choose a google plus url, but unfortunately it has to have the account in the address like this:

```
google.com/MyAccountName/MyBrandName
```

But I wanted it to be just

```
google.com/MyBrandName
```

Any clue on how to get rid of the account and remain just with the brand on Google Plus?